# How to connect client mail to postfix + dovecot server

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have “successfully” installed postfix and dovecot on my digital ocean server.

Postfix is running on `mail.<mydomain>.com` and I am able to send mail from my iCloud email to my server mail and from my server to my iCloud. The only problem is, I can only access the mail on my server by using the `mail` command. How would I be able to use it with the mail app in macOS and iOS?

If it helps, I am running Debian 9.3x64 and my postfix main.cf is the following

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/dovecot/private/mailkey.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/dovecot/private/mailcert.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.<mydomain>.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mail.<mydomain>.com, <mydomain>.com, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

Dovecote configuration:

```
##
## Mailbox locations and namespaces
##

# Location for users' mailboxes. The default is empty, which means that Dovecot
# tries to find the mailboxes automatically. This won't work if the user
# doesn't yet have any mail, so you should explicitly tell Dovecot the full
# location.
#
# If you're using mbox, giving a path to the INBOX file (eg. /var/mail/%u)
# isn't enough. You'll also need to tell Dovecot where the other mailboxes are
# kept. This is called the "root mail directory", and it must be the first
# path given in the mail_location setting.
#
# There are a few special variables you can use, eg.:
#
#   %u - username
#   %n - user part in user@domain, same as %u if there's no domain
#   %d - domain part in user@domain, empty if there's no domain
#   %h - home directory
#
# See doc/wiki/Variables.txt for full list. Some examples:
#
#   mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
#   mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
#   mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%d/%1n/%n:INDEX=/var/indexes/%d/%1n/%n
#
# <doc/wiki/MailLocation.txt>
#
#mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir

# If you need to set multiple mailbox locations or want to change default
# namespace settings, you can do it by defining namespace sections.
#
# You can have private, shared and public namespaces. Private namespaces
# are for user's personal mails. Shared namespaces are for accessing other
# users' mailboxes that have been shared. Public namespaces are for shared
# mailboxes that are managed by sysadmin. If you create any shared or public
# namespaces you'll typically want to enable ACL plugin also, otherwise all
# users can access all the shared mailboxes, assuming they have permissions
# on filesystem level to do so.
namespace inbox {
  # Namespace type: private, shared or public
  #type = private

  # Hierarchy separator to use. You should use the same separator for all
  # namespaces or some clients get confused. '/' is usually a good one.
  # The default however depends on the underlying mail storage format.
  #separator = 

  # Prefix required to access this namespace. This needs to be different for
  # all namespaces. For example "Public/".
  #prefix = 

  # Physical location of the mailbox. This is in same format as
  # mail_location, which is also the default for it.
  #location =

  # There can be only one INBOX, and this setting defines which namespace
  # has it.
  inbox = yes

  # If namespace is hidden, it's not advertised to clients via NAMESPACE
  # extension. You'll most likely also want to set list=no. This is mostly
  # useful when converting from another server with different namespaces which
  # you want to deprecate but still keep working. For example you can create
  # hidden namespaces with prefixes "~/mail/", "~%u/mail/" and "mail/".
  #hidden = no

  # Show the mailboxes under this namespace with LIST command. This makes the
  # namespace visible for clients that don't support NAMESPACE extension.
  # "children" value lists child mailboxes, but hides the namespace prefix.
  #list = yes

  # Namespace handles its own subscriptions. If set to "no", the parent
  # namespace handles them (empty prefix should always have this as "yes")
  #subscriptions = yes

  # See 15-mailboxes.conf for definitions of special mailboxes.
}

# Example shared namespace configuration
#namespace {
  #type = shared
  #separator = /

  # Mailboxes are visible under "shared/user@domain/"
  # %%n, %%d and %%u are expanded to the destination user.
  #prefix = shared/%%u/

  # Mail location for other users' mailboxes. Note that %variables and ~/
  # expands to the logged in user's data. %%n, %%d, %%u and %%h expand to the
  # destination user's data.
  #location = maildir:%%h/Maildir:INDEX=~/Maildir/shared/%%u

  # Use the default namespace for saving subscriptions.
  #subscriptions = no

  # List the shared/ namespace only if there are visible shared mailboxes.
  #list = children
#}
# Should shared INBOX be visible as "shared/user" or "shared/user/INBOX"?
#mail_shared_explicit_inbox = no

# System user and group used to access mails. If you use multiple, userdb
# can override these by returning uid or gid fields. You can use either numbers
# or names. <doc/wiki/UserIds.txt>
#mail_uid =
#mail_gid =

# Group to enable temporarily for privileged operations. Currently this is
# used only with INBOX when either its initial creation or dotlocking fails.
# Typically this is set to "mail" to give access to /var/mail.
#mail_privileged_group =

# Grant access to these supplementary groups for mail processes. Typically
# these are used to set up access to shared mailboxes. Note that it may be
# dangerous to set these if users can create symlinks (e.g. if "mail" group is
# set here, ln -s /var/mail ~/mail/var could allow a user to delete others'
# mailboxes, or ln -s /secret/shared/box ~/mail/mybox would allow reading it).
#mail_access_groups =

# Allow full filesystem access to clients. There's no access checks other than
# what the operating system does for the active UID/GID. It works with both
# maildir and mboxes, allowing you to prefix mailboxes names with eg. /path/
# or ~user/.
#mail_full_filesystem_access = no

# Dictionary for key=value mailbox attributes. This is used for example by
# URLAUTH and METADATA extensions.
#mail_attribute_dict =

# A comment or note that is associated with the server. This value is
# accessible for authenticated users through the IMAP METADATA server
# entry "/shared/comment". 
#mail_server_comment = ""

# Indicates a method for contacting the server administrator. According to
# RFC 5464, this value MUST be a URI (e.g., a mailto: or tel: URL), but that
# is currently not enforced. Use for example mailto:admin@example.com. This
# value is accessible for authenticated users through the IMAP METADATA server
# entry "/shared/admin".
#mail_server_admin = 

##
## Mail processes
##

# Don't use mmap() at all. This is required if you store indexes to shared
# filesystems (NFS or clustered filesystem).
#mmap_disable = no

# Rely on O_EXCL to work when creating dotlock files. NFS supports O_EXCL
# since version 3, so this should be safe to use nowadays by default.
#dotlock_use_excl = yes

# When to use fsync() or fdatasync() calls:
#   optimized (default): Whenever necessary to avoid losing important data
#   always: Useful with e.g. NFS when write()s are delayed
#   never: Never use it (best performance, but crashes can lose data)
#mail_fsync = optimized

# Locking method for index files. Alternatives are fcntl, flock and dotlock.
# Dotlocking uses some tricks which may create more disk I/O than other locking
# methods. NFS users: flock doesn't work, remember to change mmap_disable.
#lock_method = fcntl

# Directory in which LDA/LMTP temporarily stores incoming mails >128 kB.
#mail_temp_dir = /tmp

# Valid UID range for users, defaults to 500 and above. This is mostly
# to make sure that users can't log in as daemons or other system users.
# Note that denying root logins is hardcoded to dovecot binary and can't
# be done even if first_valid_uid is set to 0.
#first_valid_uid = 500
#last_valid_uid = 0

# Valid GID range for users, defaults to non-root/wheel. Users having
# non-valid GID as primary group ID aren't allowed to log in. If user
# belongs to supplementary groups with non-valid GIDs, those groups are
# not set.
#first_valid_gid = 1
#last_valid_gid = 0

# Maximum allowed length for mail keyword name. It's only forced when trying
# to create new keywords.
#mail_max_keyword_length = 50

# ':' separated list of directories under which chrooting is allowed for mail
# processes (ie. /var/mail will allow chrooting to /var/mail/foo/bar too).
# This setting doesn't affect login_chroot, mail_chroot or auth chroot
# settings. If this setting is empty, "/./" in home dirs are ignored.
# WARNING: Never add directories here which local users can modify, that
# may lead to root exploit. Usually this should be done only if you don't
# allow shell access for users. <doc/wiki/Chrooting.txt>
#valid_chroot_dirs = 

# Default chroot directory for mail processes. This can be overridden for
# specific users in user database by giving /./ in user's home directory
# (eg. /home/./user chroots into /home). Note that usually there is no real
# need to do chrooting, Dovecot doesn't allow users to access files outside
# their mail directory anyway. If your home directories are prefixed with
# the chroot directory, append "/." to mail_chroot. <doc/wiki/Chrooting.txt>
#mail_chroot = 

# UNIX socket path to master authentication server to find users.
# This is used by imap (for shared users) and lda.
#auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb

# Directory where to look up mail plugins.
#mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules

# Space separated list of plugins to load for all services. Plugins specific to
# IMAP, LDA, etc. are added to this list in their own .conf files.
#mail_plugins = 

##
## Mailbox handling optimizations
##

# Mailbox list indexes can be used to optimize IMAP STATUS commands. They are
# also required for IMAP NOTIFY extension to be enabled.
#mailbox_list_index = no

# The minimum number of mails in a mailbox before updates are done to cache
# file. This allows optimizing Dovecot's behavior to do less disk writes at
# the cost of more disk reads.
#mail_cache_min_mail_count = 0

# When IDLE command is running, mailbox is checked once in a while to see if
# there are any new mails or other changes. This setting defines the minimum
# time to wait between those checks. Dovecot can also use inotify and
# kqueue to find out immediately when changes occur.
#mailbox_idle_check_interval = 30 secs

# Save mails with CR+LF instead of plain LF. This makes sending those mails
# take less CPU, especially with sendfile() syscall with Linux and FreeBSD.
# But it also creates a bit more disk I/O which may just make it slower.
# Also note that if other software reads the mboxes/maildirs, they may handle
# the extra CRs wrong and cause problems.
#mail_save_crlf = no

# Max number of mails to keep open and prefetch to memory. This only works with
# some mailbox formats and/or operating systems.
#mail_prefetch_count = 0

# How often to scan for stale temporary files and delete them (0 = never).
# These should exist only after Dovecot dies in the middle of saving mails.
#mail_temp_scan_interval = 1w

##
## Maildir-specific settings
##

# By default LIST command returns all entries in maildir beginning with a dot.
# Enabling this option makes Dovecot return only entries which are directories.
# This is done by stat()ing each entry, so it causes more disk I/O.
# (For systems setting struct dirent->d_type, this check is free and it's
# done always regardless of this setting)
#maildir_stat_dirs = no

# When copying a message, do it with hard links whenever possible. This makes
# the performance much better, and it's unlikely to have any side effects.
#maildir_copy_with_hardlinks = yes

# Assume Dovecot is the only MUA accessing Maildir: Scan cur/ directory only
# when its mtime changes unexpectedly or when we can't find the mail otherwise.
#maildir_very_dirty_syncs = no

# If enabled, Dovecot doesn't use the S=<size> in the Maildir filenames for
# getting the mail's physical size, except when recalculating Maildir++ quota.
# This can be useful in systems where a lot of the Maildir filenames have a
# broken size. The performance hit for enabling this is very small.
#maildir_broken_filename_sizes = no

# Always move mails from new/ directory to cur/, even when the \Recent flags
# aren't being reset.
#maildir_empty_new = no

##
## mbox-specific settings
##

# Which locking methods to use for locking mbox. There are four available:
#  dotlock: Create <mailbox>.lock file. This is the oldest and most NFS-safe
#           solution. If you want to use /var/mail/ like directory, the users
#           will need write access to that directory.
#  dotlock_try: Same as dotlock, but if it fails because of permissions or
#               because there isn't enough disk space, just skip it.
#  fcntl  : Use this if possible. Works with NFS too if lockd is used.
#  flock  : May not exist in all systems. Doesn't work with NFS.
#  lockf  : May not exist in all systems. Doesn't work with NFS.
#
# You can use multiple locking methods; if you do the order they're declared
# in is important to avoid deadlocks if other MTAs/MUAs are using multiple
# locking methods as well. Some operating systems don't allow using some of
# them simultaneously.
#
# The Debian value for mbox_write_locks differs from upstream Dovecot. It is
# changed to be compliant with Debian Policy (section 11.6) for NFS safety.
#       Dovecot: mbox_write_locks = dotlock fcntl
#       Debian:  mbox_write_locks = fcntl dotlock
#
#mbox_read_locks = fcntl
#mbox_write_locks = fcntl dotlock

# Maximum time to wait for lock (all of them) before aborting.
#mbox_lock_timeout = 5 mins

# If dotlock exists but the mailbox isn't modified in any way, override the
# lock file after this much time.
#mbox_dotlock_change_timeout = 2 mins

# When mbox changes unexpectedly we have to fully read it to find out what
# changed. If the mbox is large this can take a long time. Since the change
# is usually just a newly appended mail, it'd be faster to simply read the
# new mails. If this setting is enabled, Dovecot does this but still safely
# fallbacks to re-reading the whole mbox file whenever something in mbox isn't
# how it's expected to be. The only real downside to this setting is that if
# some other MUA changes message flags, Dovecot doesn't notice it immediately.
# Note that a full sync is done with SELECT, EXAMINE, EXPUNGE and CHECK 
# commands.
#mbox_dirty_syncs = yes

# Like mbox_dirty_syncs, but don't do full syncs even with SELECT, EXAMINE,
# EXPUNGE or CHECK commands. If this is set, mbox_dirty_syncs is ignored.
#mbox_very_dirty_syncs = no

# Delay writing mbox headers until doing a full write sync (EXPUNGE and CHECK
# commands and when closing the mailbox). This is especially useful for POP3
# where clients often delete all mails. The downside is that our changes
# aren't immediately visible to other MUAs.
#mbox_lazy_writes = yes

# If mbox size is smaller than this (e.g. 100k), don't write index files.
# If an index file already exists it's still read, just not updated.
#mbox_min_index_size = 0

# Mail header selection algorithm to use for MD5 POP3 UIDLs when
# pop3_uidl_format=%m. For backwards compatibility we use apop3d inspired
# algorithm, but it fails if the first Received: header isn't unique in all
# mails. An alternative algorithm is "all" that selects all headers.
#mbox_md5 = apop3d

##
## mdbox-specific settings
##

# Maximum dbox file size until it's rotated.
#mdbox_rotate_size = 2M

# Maximum dbox file age until it's rotated. Typically in days. Day begins
# from midnight, so 1d = today, 2d = yesterday, etc. 0 = check disabled.
#mdbox_rotate_interval = 0

# When creating new mdbox files, immediately preallocate their size to
# mdbox_rotate_size. This setting currently works only in Linux with some
# filesystems (ext4, xfs).
#mdbox_preallocate_space = no

##
## Mail attachments
##

# sdbox and mdbox support saving mail attachments to external files, which
# also allows single instance storage for them. Other backends don't support
# this for now.

# Directory root where to store mail attachments. Disabled, if empty.
#mail_attachment_dir =

# Attachments smaller than this aren't saved externally. It's also possible to
# write a plugin to disable saving specific attachments externally.
#mail_attachment_min_size = 128k

# Filesystem backend to use for saving attachments:
#  posix : No SiS done by Dovecot (but this might help FS's own deduplication)
#  sis posix : SiS with immediate byte-by-byte comparison during saving
#  sis-queue posix : SiS with delayed comparison and deduplication
#mail_attachment_fs = sis posix

# Hash format to use in attachment filenames. You can add any text and
# variables: %{md4}, %{md5}, %{sha1}, %{sha256}, %{sha512}, %{size}.
# Variables can be truncated, e.g. %{sha256:80} returns only first 80 bits
#mail_attachment_hash = %{sha1}
```

Also here is what I tried doing in mail.app on my iPhone and iPad:

[image]

Please note: `<name>` = Debian username and `<mydomain>` is my domain name.

After clicking next, I get the following error:

[image]

I get this error when using both IMAP and POP3.

How can I connect Mail.app to my server?

Comment: Hmm. Were you following some tutorial on the Internet? It looks like you may have skipped several steps in such a tutorial. Check that Dovecot is running, that you opened the right ports in your firewall, and then go back to that tutorial and see if you can find the steps you missed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I cannot find the tutorial I was using. However, I have came across another tutorial about enabling IMAP. I don’t remember the other tutorial going through that. Trying it now.

Comment: Bit overkill for a single domain but it works really well - https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie

Comment: @MichaelHampton Just found the tutorial that I was using, nowhere does it mention how to setup IMAP or POP3. https://www.vultr.com/docs/simple-mailserver-postfix-dovecot-sieve-debian